# BitmapSource to BitmapImage

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, bitmapimage, bitmapsource

I need to parse the content of `Clipboard.GetImage()` (a `BitmapSource`) to a `BitmapImage`. 
Does anyone knows how can this be done?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I've found a clean solution that works:

```
BitmapSource bitmapSource = Clipboard.GetImage();

JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
BitmapImage bImg = new BitmapImage();

encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapSource));
encoder.Save(memoryStream);

memoryStream.Position = 0;
bImg.BeginInit();
bImg.StreamSource = memoryStream;
bImg.EndInit();

memoryStream.Close();

return bImg;
```

Comment: Is it necessary to use `bImg.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(memoryStream.ToArray());` instead of `bImg.StreamSource = memoryStream;` and removing `memoryStream.Close();
`

Comment: You should add bImg.Freeze() at the end to allow multithreaded calls, otherwise works perfect.

Comment: @Don'tForgettoUpvote: For me `bImg.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(memoryStream.ToArray());` was necessary, else it was throwing exception.

Comment: What if a PNG image is in the clipboard? Should you use the PngBitmapEncoder then?

Comment: @Elmo The changes were indeed required, without them, it was throwing exception for me too

Comment: Is this even lossless?

Answer (score 2):

```
using System.IO; // namespace for  using MemoryStream

private static byte[] ReadImageMemory()
{
    BitmapSource bitmapSource = BitmapConversion.ToBitmapSource(Clipboard.GetImage());
    JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapSource));
    encoder.Save(memoryStream);
    return memoryStream.GetBuffer();
}

// and calling by this example........
byte[] buffer = ReadImageMemory();
```