# Create a BitmapImage from ushort[]

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap, bitmapimage, imagesource

Is it possible to create a BitmapImage from a ushort array? and if so how?

At the minute I'm creating a Bitmap, converting it to a Bitmap array and displaying it, but this is too slow, I need to continuously update the image (live video feed), while each frame is being created the UI studders, this is making my app very slow when video is running. So I need to get my ushort[] into a BitmapImage as fast as possible

Thanks,
Eamonn

Comment: image data, numbers from 0 - 65000, represents a grayscale image

Comment: man, this is information that should have been in your question when you asked it!! remember this for your next question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're working with values between `0` and `255` you could cast it into an array of bytes and then load it into a `MemoryStream`:

```
// Please note that with values higher than 255 the program will throw an exception
checked
{
    ushort[] values = { 200, 100, 30/*, 256*/ };
    var bytes = (from value in values
                 select (byte)value).ToArray();

    // Taken from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346727/wpf-convert-memory-stream-to-bitmapimage
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(data))
    {
        var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        bitmap.BeginInit();
        bitmap.StreamSource = stream;
        bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        bitmap.EndInit();
        bitmap.Freeze();
    }
}
```

Comment: the data is 0 - 65000 but I will try scaling it down and see if this method is faster than my current one

Answer (score 2):

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338253/bitmapsource-to-bitmapimage/5338514#5338514) you have an example of how to get a BitmapImage through a MemoryStream, this might help you

you can use [BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx) to convert ushorts to byte for input to MemoryStream