# How to convert a CroppedBitmap to BitmapImage

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to convert a CroppedBitmap to BitmapImage *** EDIT:Without using a memorystream.***

I have tried to directly convert it, seems that is not an option.  This should't be that hard.

I am attempting to cut out part of a BitmapImage, and create a BitmapImage that contains only the new cropped Bitmap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would seem a BitmapImage is a specialized version of BitmapSource (which is what a CroppedBitmap is).  You can easily convert from Image to source, but not the otherway around.

This answer likely works, though I never looked into it.

[BitmapSource to BitmapImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338253/bitmapsource-to-bitmapimage)

The easiest solution for me was to convert all my BitmapImages into BitmapSources.  I didn't even have to edit any other code.  I guess I wasn't using the specialized parts.

Comment: For many use cases it would even be sufficient to use `ImageSource`, which is the base class of `BitmapSource`. For example the `Source` property of the `Image` control is of type `ImageSource`.

Comment: And this is what MSDN say about `BitmapImage` (in the Remarks [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.aspx)): *BitmapImage primarily exists to support Extensible Application Markup Language (XAML) syntax and introduces additional properties for bitmap loading that are not defined by BitmapSource.`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this
Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(Image file path or image stream);
after that use the save function like this
bm.Save(Image path,format);

Comment: Not sure I follow. Bitmap is used in Winforms, BitmapImage/BitmapSource are from WPF.  Are you suggesting mixing the two?...  how do you get the BitmapImage into a Bitmap to Beginwith?