# How to save a "CroppedBitmap"

Tags: wpf, vb.net, save, bitmapimage

I created a cropped Bitmap and now i want to save it. I know how to save a bitmapframe, but i dont know how to convert it to a bitmapframe.

Code:

```
' Create an Image element.
    Dim croppedImage As New Image()
    croppedImage.Width = 200
    croppedImage.Margin = New Thickness(5)

    ' Create a CroppedBitmap based off of a xaml defined resource.
    Dim cb As New CroppedBitmap(CType(screenshot, BitmapSource), New Int32Rect(X, Y, breite, höhe))
    'select region rect
    croppedImage.Source = cb 'set image source to cropped
```

So I want to save the new Image as file.

Comment: some ideas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21275602/how-to-convert-a-croppedbitmap-to-bitmapimage

Answer (score 0):

Hi i did the same thing in C#, i hope you can convert into vb

```
void saveCroppedBitmap(CroppedBitmap image,string path)
{
    FileStream mStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
    JpegBitmapEncoder jEncoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
    jEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image)); 
    jEncoder.Save(mStream);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
private void CropBitmap(BitmapFrame bitmapFrame,int height,string filename,BitmapEncoder encoder)
{
    CroppedBitmap croppedBitmap = new CroppedBitmap(bitmapFrame, new Int32Rect(0,0,(int)bitmapFrame.Width, height));

    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(croppedBitmap));

    using (System.IO.FileStream fs = File.Create(filename))
    {
        encoder.Save(fs);
    }

}
```