# WPF: Converting a BitmapImage to an array and edit it, then recreating it

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap, bitmapsource

I want to develop a Steganography software in WPF, so I need direct access to pixels, I am trying to convert a Bitmap to an array and edit it, the problem is I can only recreate it by BitmapSource (am I right?) and I can't recreate it correctly. I get a Black and White Image instead.

```
public static void Conceal(BitmapImage CoverPhotoBitmap, BitmapImage HiddenPhotoBitmap, ref BitmapSource ResultPhotoBitmapSource)
{
    int stride = CoverPhotoBitmap.PixelWidth * 4;
    int size = CoverPhotoBitmap.PixelHeight * stride;
    byte[] CoverPhotoPixels = new byte[size];
    CoverPhotoBitmap.CopyPixels(CoverPhotoPixels, stride, 0);

    byte[] HiddenPhotoPixels = new byte[size];
    HiddenPhotoBitmap.CopyPixels(HiddenPhotoPixels, stride, 0);
    ResultPhotoBitmapSource = BitmapSource.Create(CoverPhotoBitmap.PixelWidth, CoverPhotoBitmap.PixelHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Rgb32, null, HiddenPhotoPixels, stride);
}
```

Comment: What's the error? - "I can't write it back correctly" does not tell us anything.

Comment: I get a Black and White Image instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [BitmapImage to byte\[\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6597676/bitmapimage-to-byte)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14337071/convert-array-of-bytes-to-bitmapimage

Comment: Are you sure that `PixelFormats.Rgb32` is the correct pixel format? You may probably better use `CoverPhotoBitmap.Format` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may convert your resulting `BitmapSource` to a `BitmapImage`. Check the answer to this question: [BitmapSource to BitmapImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338253/bitmapsource-to-bitmapimage).

Not marking as duplicate since it's not the same question, although the answer applies.

Comment: I read that page before, I don't need to convert Bitmap to BitmapSource directly, in fact I need my "array" to be converted to a BitmapSource (or a Bitmap if it is possible).
I want to be able to use it as ResultPhoto.Source in visual mode (xaml)

Comment: I thought by reading your question that your problem was converting the `BitmapSource` to a `BitmapImage`... if your problem is converting back from the array, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14337071/convert-array-of-bytes-to-bitmapimage